# Does this loose insulation look like it might contain asbestos?

Tags: insulation, asbestos

Was remodeling my bathroom, and after ripping open the ceiling a bunch of this loose insulation fell down out of my attic. Does this loose insulation from my attic look like it might contain asbestos?
[image: The attic insulation in question]

Comment: A guess is that is a cellulose based insulation. To be sure get it tested.

Comment: To amplify @SolarMike -- the only way you'll know is to get it tested.

Comment: how old is the house?

Comment: @LarryBud House was built in 1978.